# Finding possible misconceptions in ColumnChart

Tags: c#

I've written this to accomplish a specific problem, but it's too long. I've sure that it can be reduce too fit it.

I have the following model:

```
public class ColumnChart
{        
    public virtual string type { get; set; }
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<double> data { get; set; }
}
```

- The idea of `List<double>` is to keep 12 values (1 per month if exists)
- All these 12 values has to belong someone, so the `name` will keep the legend.
- The type is `column` (not always, but in this case will make it simple).

**Big Logic**

```
// Create a List of ColumnChart's
var list = new List<ColumnChart>();

// Instantiate one object of type ColumnChart
var serie = new ColumnChart();

// Instantiate the List<double> (like my model says)
serie.data = new List<double>();

// Control the loop
int i = 0;

foreach (var element in MyDataSource)
{
   // If the serie.name don't have the current Group Name that came from my DataSource
   if (serie.name != element.GroupName)
   {
       // Isn't the first loop ?
       if (i != 0)
       {
           // Return a new empty instance of ChartColumn
           serie = NewInstance();

           // Set the legend that belong all data
           serie.name = element.GroupName;

           // Set the type of the chart
           serie.type = "column";

           // Instantiate a new List<double> (like my model says)
           serie.data = new List<double>();

           if (serie.data.Count == element.Month - 1)
           {
               serie.data.Insert(element.Month - 1, element.ValueRevenue);
           }

           // If the number of elements in my List<double> is lower then the Month.
           else
           {
               while (serie.data.Count < element.Month - 1)
               {
                   serie.data.Add(0);
               }

              serie.data.Insert(element.Month - 1, element.ValueRevenue);
            }
       }

       // Is the first loop interaction
       else
       {
            serie.name = element.GroupName;
            serie.type = "column";
            serie.data.Insert(element.Month - 1, elemento.ValueRevenue);
            i++;
        }
   }

   // The serie.name have the same current Group Name that came from my DataSource
   else
   {
       serie.data.Insert(element.Month - 1, element.ValueRevenue);
       i++;
   }

   // My i variable that control the loop is the last interaction ?
   if (i == MyDataSource.Count() - 1)
   {
       list.Add(serie);
   }
}

i = 0;
```

**Data Source**

> ```
> MyDataSource
>       [0]  
>            Month: 1
>            GroupName: 'Music'
>            ValueRevenue: 700.0
>       [1]  
>            Month: 2
>            GroupName: 'Music'
>            ValueRevenue: 700.0
>       [2]  
>            Month: 3
>            GroupName: 'Music'
>            ValueRevenue: 700.0
>       [3]  
>            Month: 4
>            GroupName: 'Music'
>            ValueRevenue: 700.0
>       [4]  
>            Month: 5
>            GroupName: 'Music'
>            ValueRevenue: 700.0
>       [5]  
>            Month: 6
>            GroupName: 'Music'
>            ValueRevenue: 700.0
>       [6]  
>            Month: 7
>            GroupName: 'Music'
>            ValueRevenue: 700.0
>       [7]  
>            Month: 8
>            GroupName: 'Music'
>            ValueRevenue: 700.0
>       [8]  
>            Month: 9
>            GroupName: 'Car'
>            ValueRevenue: 700.0
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if this can be solved using `Linq`.

If your datasource consists an `IEnumerable` of records each containing a **MonthNumber**, **GroupName** and **ValueRevenue**

Say,

```
public class DataRecord {

    public int MonthNbr { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public double ValueRevenue { get; set; }

}
```

then a `GroupBy()` should populate your `ChartColumn`

e.g.

```
private static ColumnChart GroupAndSort(IEnumerable<DataRecord> input) {

    return input.GroupBy(n => n.GroupName).Select(g => new ColumnChart {
            Type = "column",
            Name = g.Key,
            Data = g.OrderBy(d => d.MonthNbr).Select(d => d.ValueRevenue).ToList()
        }).First();

}
```

**Note**:

This was set up to deal with one set of records and only one `ChartColumn` being generated. If you have many groups in the input then remove the 'First()' and return an 'IEnumerable'